# C++ error: "Unable to start program 'filepath.exe' The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, compilation

Using Visual Studios 2017 (Updated last week). Get the error "Unable to start program "filepath.exe" the system cannot find the file specified.

Below is the "Hello World" function I'm running, but the issue isn't with the code, it's somewhere in my setup. I had Visual Studios working 6 months ago to start learning C++, but now that I've come back and updated VS, it isn't working anymore.

The code compiles okay (or so it says), but then throws the error above when I attempt to use the local windows debugger to run the code. When I searched for the "filepath.exe" file, but it isn't in the specified folder, nor can I find a .exe file of any kind anywhere within the project working directory. There are a lot of questions on stackoverflow that go over this issue, but none of them solved my problem.

I checked all the properties (Solution explorer >> Project Name >> Properties) and here is my current setup:

**General:**

Output Directory: $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\
Intermediate Directory: $(Configuration)\
Target Name: $(ProjectName)
Target Extension: .exe

**Debugging:**

Command: $(TargetPath)
Working Directory: $(ProjectDir)
Attach: "No"
Debugger Type: "Auto"

**Linker:**

Output File:$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)
Show Progress: Not Set

I'm using a single .cpp file in a "blank" type C++ Project.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello StackOverFlow";
    return 0;
}
```

Any help on how to go about troubleshooting this would be helpful. New to compiled languages.

Comment: If the executable isn't located on your drive, then either the compilation failed or you've got an issue with your anti-virus software (which is deleting the executable that suddenly appears because it may be malware). Does the problem go away if you temporarily disable your AV software?

Comment: The executable must be somewhere on my drive I think, because if I build the project again it tells me that it is up-to-date and doesn't build it again. I tried turning of my ant-virus and I get the same problem. Any other thoughts?

Comment: *The executable must be somewhere on my drive I think* Did you search for it (via Explorer) to find out, instead of guessing? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw the problem in your code which is *actually giving you an error*. Your code is as follows:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        cout << "Hello StackOverFlow";
        return 0;
    }
```

If you notice closely, you have not left a space in ***between*** `#include<iostream>` which is giving you a run time error and states that the specified file cannot be found. If you left space as in:

```
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
     int main() {
         cout << "Hello StackOverFlow";
         return 0;
     }
```

It will not give you an error. I hope this helps you overcome the issue. Glad to help you Phillips! :)

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me too sometimes when I was new to the language. It usually occurs when you accidentally delete the file. So you can solve this issue by creating a new C++ empty project, enter a new item: the source-code file and then copy this code in the new file. It should work equally well and good.
I hope my answer helped you overcome the issue! :)

Comment: Still no luck :/. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try installing Visual studio again. Also, I would recommend shifting to VS 2019 if possible. I hope this solves your issue! ;)